# no puedo exportar datos a un csv con StringBuilder

Tags: java

mi duda es la siguiente estoy intentando manipular una cadena con la clase `StringBuilder`, esta cadena sera manipulada con substrings y replace, hasta ahi todo perfecto, hago la comprobación imprimiendo los datos y los  pinta sin problemas pero al exportarlo en un documento  CSV tengo los campos vacíos. ¿Cual podría ser el problema?.

```
public class ExportToCsv {

    private static final String FILE_NAME = "stackoverflow.xlsx";

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("PruebaParser");



        System.out.println("Escribe tu registro");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder(sc.nextLine());
        StringBuilder strbNuevo = new StringBuilder(strb); 
        StringBuilder strbNuevo1 = new StringBuilder(strb);


        strb.replace(0, 4, "1234");
        System.out.println(strb);

        strbNuevo.replace(4 ,7, "AAA");
        System.out.println(strbNuevo);

        strbNuevo1.replace(7, 10, "BBB");
        System.out.println(strbNuevo1);



        Object[][] datatypes = {
                {"Datos", "Type"},
                {strb, 1},
                {strbNuevo, 2},
                {strbNuevo1,3}

        };

        int rowNum = 0;
        System.out.println("Creating excel");

        for (Object[] datatype : datatypes) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
            int colNum = 0;
            for (Object field : datatype) {
                Cell cell = row.createCell(colNum++);
                if (field instanceof String) {
                    cell.setCellValue((String) field);
                } else if (field instanceof Integer) {
                    cell.setCellValue((Integer) field);
                }
            }
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(FILE_NAME);
            workbook.write(outputStream);
            workbook.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

La salida por consola:

```
Escribe tu registro
134400000000000000000000000000`

123400000000000000000000000000
1344AAA00000000000000000000000
1344000BBB00000000000000000000
Creating excel
Done
```

Esto mismo quiero insetarlo en el CSV como lo esta  pintando pero cuando lo exporto esta vacío solo se muestran los numeros 1,2 y 3 que es la celda de Type.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias!

Comment: no tienes código para exportarloa csv sino a excel y dudo que streamBuilder sea serializxable. Por favor indica quelibrerías usas y como pretendes que tu xls se convierta en un excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema está aquí:

```
if (field instanceof String) {
```

Estás testeando si el dato es de tipo String, pero tu pusiste tipo StringBuilder en tu array, por lo tanto la condición no se cumple nunca y no se agrega a la celda.
La opción es que conviertas a String tan pronto como no necesites manipular los datos:

```
        Object[][] datatypes = {
            {"Datos", "Type"},
            {strb.toString(), 1},
            {strbNuevo.toString(), 2},
            {strbNuevo1.toString(),3}

    };
```